# jQuery Color else condition takes 17 second to respinse

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-color

I have tested it on every browser I have on my computer.
I even tried it with error handling and found no issue.

The script is quite simple and it work but not quite like it supposed to

When you scroll down the bar will change the color to red, but when you scroll up it supposed to change it to green(Its not the real concept but I tried to change the code and chose random colors)

What happens is that it changes the color to red instantly like it supposed to do, but when it hits the top again and supposed to change it to green it takes almost 20 seconds to respond.

Here is the full code

```js
(function(){
    
    "use strict";
    
   $(document).ready(function(){
       
            var advancedNav = $('.navigation').offset().top;

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > advancedNav ) {
                    $(".navigation").animate({
                        "background-color": "red"
                    }, 1000)
                } 
                else {
                   $(".navigation").animate({
                        "background-color": "green"
                    }, 1000)
                }
            });
    });
    
})();
```

```css
.navigation {
    
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0);
    z-index: 1;
    
}


.navigation ul {
    
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.navigation li {
    
    float: left;
    
}

.navigation  li a {
    
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: barelFont;
    
}

.navigation  li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#everest">Main</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projectsSection">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutSection">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contactSection">Contact</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</header>
```

What I tried is to try and use the original jquery css() method and it works like a charm.

But I want it to change dynamically and look good so I tried it with Jquery Color and JqueryUI and the same thing is happening.

What can be the cause of the problem here?

Comment: You are probably hitting the time it is taking for the animation queue to get to your final animation.  Your first if logic is not taking into account if it has already animated to red.  The scroll event fires *a ton*.  I would suggest throttling the handler, and possibly adding some way to know that you are already animating to red and don't kick off another animate to red until that is done/needed again.

Comment: I wouldn't be thinking much about the animation queue since the commands are quite simple, and to be fair it did work before. I didn't consider trying to force it to stop right after it changes the color to red but it works now. Thanks a lot mate you really helped me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that too many animations are being added to the animation queue as pointed by @Taplar.

I'd suggest to switch CSS classes instead:

```js
(function(){
    
    "use strict";
    
   $(document).ready(function(){
       
            var advancedNav = $('.navigation').offset().top;

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > advancedNav ) {
                    $(".navigation").removeClass('green').addClass("red")
                } 
                else {
                   $(".navigation").removeClass('red').addClass("green")
                }
            });
    });
    
})();
```

```css
body, html {height:100%}
header {height:200%}
.navigation {
    
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0);
    z-index: 1;
    transition:background-color 1s
    
}
.green {background-color: green}
.red   {background-color: red}


.navigation ul {
    
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.navigation li {
    
    float: left;
    
}

.navigation  li a {
    
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: barelFont;
    
}

.navigation  li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#everest">Main</a></li>
          <li><a href="#projectsSection">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#aboutSection">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contactSection">Contact</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</header>
```